# Trying to set an array to a range, get error in one instance, not another

Tags: excel, vba

```
 Da_Array = Range("$A15:$z26")
```

gets no error, and assigns with no problem, but when I try this....

```
Da_Array = Sheets(1).Range(Cells(Range("_FilterDatabase").Row, _ 
  Range("_FilterDatabase").Column).Address & ":" & _ 
  Cells(Range("_FilterDatabase").Row + 11, Range("_FilterDatabase").Column + 125).Address)
```

anyone know why?  I walked through the code and couldn't figure it out.  When I highlighted the part starting with "Cells" I did get the same address, ("$A15:$z26")  I'm stuck.  any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Try putting `.Value` on the end?

Comment: @ScottCraner DOH!  that did it, thanks!  Why don't you put that in an answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: Glad to help, I make it a habit to always put the `.Value` after then I do not need to worry as much.  As to why one needs it and the other does not I do not know.  And since I can only give you the end without the why I prefer to leave it as a comment.  Good Luck.

Comment: Another thing to try which should be equivalent: `Da_Array = Sheets(1).Range(Cells(Range("_FilterDatabase").Row, Range("_FilterDatabase").Column), Cells(Range("_FilterDatabase").Row + 11, Range("_FilterDatabase").Column + 125))`.  Note use of the two arguments of the Range object.  It is hard to imagine that .column + 125 would result in Column Z, though.

Comment: You should also note that, with the syntax you are using, you will probably see a `1004` error if Sheets(1) is not the active sheet when you run the macro.  This is due to the various `Cells` objects not having a defined object to reference.  You can either prefix each instance with `Sheets(1)`, or use a `With ...End With` construct.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld  Thank you.  The "125" was a typographical error on my part, and thank you for your advice.